# Debug PHP code from input passed in a html form with xdebug and NetBeans 8.2

Tags: php, html, debugging, netbeans

I have set up XDebug extension to debug PHP code from within NetBeans IDE (ver. 8.2). Debugging is working fine when I set a breakpoint and run the script in debug mode.

Now I have a HTML5 code which includes a form with 4 user inputs and a submint button which passes them all to my PHP code. However I am having difficulties in debugging the PHP with the inputs passed from the HTML page. I tried to set a breakpoint in the called PHP code, but after pressing the submit button I cannot reach the breakpoint, although the debug session seems always "in progress".

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2 web server, PHP 7, and Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in an [old post](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-100923.html) the NetBeans Forum.
My setup was:

- `index.html` contains the form
- `code.php` processes it

The solution was to change the extension of the index from `.html` to `.php`. Then in the Project settings under Run Configuration, I set up the new `index.php` file as the "Index File". Finally, setting a breakpoint in the `code.php`, made it stops in debug mode after the form in `index.php` was submitted.

Hope this could be of help for anybody.